# PHP. Loop through an array and get items with attributes in common

Tags: php, arrays

How can I loop through this array and get arrays with only similar values. In the example below, I would like to have an array that contains items 2, 3 and 4 because they all have category_parent => 4 in common.

I need to loop through that array so that I get the following result.

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1
    <ul>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Comercial
            [slug] => comercial
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [cat_ID] => 3
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Comercial
            [category_nicename] => comercial
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Escolar
            [slug] => escolar
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [cat_ID] => 4
            [category_count] => 0
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Escolar
            [category_nicename] => escolar
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [name] => Kinder
            [slug] => kinder
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 4
            [count] => 1
            [cat_ID] => 5
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Kinder
            [category_nicename] => kinder
            [category_parent] => 4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 6
            [name] => Primaria
            [slug] => primaria
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 6
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 4
            [count] => 1
            [cat_ID] => 6
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Primaria
            [category_nicename] => primaria
            [category_parent] => 4
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 7
            [name] => Secundaria
            [slug] => secundaria
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 7
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 4
            [count] => 2
            [cat_ID] => 7
            [category_count] => 2
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Secundaria
            [category_nicename] => secundaria
            [category_parent] => 4
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 1
            [name] => Uncategorized
            [slug] => uncategorized
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 1
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [cat_ID] => 1
            [category_count] => 1
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Uncategorized
            [category_nicename] => uncategorized
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "similar values"?  Which values?  How "close" do the values have to be to each other to be "similar"?

Comment: The example is array items 2, 3 and 4 because they all have same category_parent => 4

Comment: Okay, so loop through the array and only pick out those subarrays with `category_parent==4`.

Comment: If you want something different, you're going to have to coherently explain what you want to do rather than give one example and hope that we're mind readers (Hint: we're not) and can divine what you actually want to do.

Comment: The problem is, I have to create HTML lists on the fly. so `<ul><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>`

Comment: HTML lists consisting of **what**?  Please start from the beginning and explain--in coherently-written English, please--exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: there, updated question. subcategories under categories. note how 2, 3 and 4 far same category_parent.

Comment: Okay, so if you want to output that list, just output it...  **What**, if anything, does that have to do with your arrays?  **Please stop pretending that we can read your mind.  We can't.**  Start at the **beginning** and coherently describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: That array it's the output of `$categories = get_categories();` using wordpress. I need to create a very customized list. so in order for me to do that, i need to manipulate that array and create that list i showed in the question. the list has more stuff, but as long as i get that basic list i can add the markup and everything else.

Comment: I still have no idea how you want these lists generated.  I still have no idea what you mean by "similar values" (exactly equal?  If so, for which keys?). If you actually want help, you'll need to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$filtered = array_filter($original, function ($class) {
    return $class->category_parent === 4;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored in a new array.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $element) {
    if($element->category_parent == 4) {
        $result[] = $element;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: He needs to check the multidimensional array for common values, not `if value == x`

Comment: @w0rldart - OP is either unable or unwilling to elaborate on what he means other than he wants all of the subarrays with the `category_parent` value to equal 4.

Comment: I'm answering his specific need to filter the `category_parent` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $element){
  if ($element->category_parent == 4)
    $ret[] = $key;
}
//$ret is the final array
```

Comment: sorry that saves the indexes not the items. if you want to save the items, Muhammad Abrar's answer will do