# dynamically create arrays from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So if having a multidimensional array like:

Got it from here (as a demo): [PHP. Loop through an array and get items with attributes in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220737/php-loop-through-an-array-and-get-items-with-attributes-in-common)

`$data`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [name] => Comercial
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Escolar
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [name] => Kinder
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 6
            [name] => Primaria
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 7
            [name] => Secundaria
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 1
            [name] => Uncategorized
        )

)
```

Having 0,1,2,3,4,5 `stdClass Object`s, how can I create individual arrays for each `std Object` dynamically.

By that I mean that the function should be able to create `$varX` array, where X is the array number of the stdObject, automatically...

`$var0 = $data[0];`
`$var1 = $data[1];`
and so on, determined by `$data` first level count of arrays.

---

**Edit:**
I got carried away and forgot to mention the most important question:

Having `$var0`, `$var1`... is very important because for a later use of all or each one individually.

So

- Needs to create X variables according to the count of first level of the multidimensional array
- each `$varX` needs to be accessible in common with the rest of `$varX` or individually.

  `$count = count($data); //6`

  `foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  {
     $var.$key = $value;
  }`

Ok, that function works partially because from there I don't know how to make it automatically add `$val1`,`$val2`... to (ex:) `array_intersect($val1,$val2,$val3...`

Comment: Curious as to why you would want to do this? i.e. What do you plan to accomplish with $var0 that you can't with $data[0] ?

Comment: check the edit to see why, I had forgotten to ask it the first time

Comment: I think you are confused. I don't think embedding the array key into the lvalue is ever the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [`extract`](http://ca.php.net/extract).

```
extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
```

With that said, it will add an underscore (`_`) after the prefix (e.g. `var_0`).

**Update:**

Regarding your edit, you could simply call `array_intersect` using [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array). There's no need for variables.

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $data);
```

Comment: +1, wow I really like how the solution you offer looks. I will test it tomorrow, now is time to nap :D. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast each object to an array.

```
foreach ($data AS $key => $datum)
{
    $data[$key] = (array) $datum;
}
```

---

For your update:

```
foreach ($data AS $key => $datum)
{
    $newkey = 'var' . $key; // we want the variable to be called "var" plus the number
    $$newkey = (array) $datum; // Make it an array
    $data[$key] = $$newkey; // And update the $data array to contain the array
}
```

You now have `$var0`, `$var1`, etc and can also access them as a collection in `$data`, and they're in both as an array.

Comment: hmmm, I don't see how (me) I could run the `array_intersect` with all the values $key have. I didn't try, but I don't think running `array_intersect($key)` after the `foreach` will work, neither inside it.

Comment: Rather than saying "I want to extract these vars as an array", "I want to intersect them", why not just say "I have this data [paste], I need to get it to look like this [paste], how do I do it?" :) Much easier to answer.

Comment: Sorry @Joe if my question wasn't clear enough, sometimes its really hard for me to express my questions by writing them, and I'm still improving my Technical English skill to make better questions and answers. But thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Not a problem. When you're converting data like this (from objects nested in an array to whatever you needed), just saying "From [this] to [this] - how?" gets us to think how we'd do it, which (no offence) is probably more efficient than how you'd do it (just based on the fact you're asking for help) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $obj)
{
  $key = 'var'.$key;
  $$key = $obj;
}
```